# Escaped International characters?

Tags: php, character-encoding

I am looking at some PHP code where there are translation strings.
For French there are characters that I have never seen before and I am asking if someone could shed a light.

These strings are used as HTML output, but also as body text to send emails.

```
È = é
Ë = è
‡ = à
Í = ê
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RHS (é, è, à, ê) are in [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (and Unicode) encoding.

The LHS (È, Ë, ‡, Í) are the corresponding characters in [Mac-Roman encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) with the same code-point.

Comment: I thank you very much indeed! Can I use this safely to send emails with characters like that in the body to my clients you think?